# Is "Barista Exchange" confusing for users?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Have you guys seen this site?
http://www.baristaexchange.com/

Looks very similar to stackexchanges' site. For example, look at the header.

This seems confusing for our users. Is it also IP infringement?

Answer (score 7):

It's a discussion board with the word "exchange" in its name. This isn't a discussion board, and we hardly have a monopoly on the word "exchange".

Also there are a crapload of ads on that thing, which should make it obvious pretty quickly that it's a whole different sort of party.

I don't think it'll be a problem.